# How to show many links separate by value in D3.js forced directed graph

Tags: php, d3.js

### It overlapping lines

I try to show many links between nodes by multi array (Source,Target,Value)
But It's not display.It overlapping lines.

[My Example] http://bl.ocks.org/Lovekiizzk/90cbfb9d8ee7fe9baa26

See in the knet2.json.

```
{
"nodes":[
 {
"name":"Novak_Djokovic",
"thumbnail":"http:\/\/commons.wikimedia.org\/wiki\/Special:FilePath\/Flickr_-_Carine06_-_Novak_Djokovic_(4).jpg?width=300",
"uri":"http:\/\/dbpedia.org\/resource\/Novak_Djokovic",
"group":1},
{
"name":"Rafael_Nadal",
"thumbnail":"http:\/\/commons.wikimedia.org\/wiki\/Special:FilePath\/Rafael_Nadal_January_2015.jpg?width=300",
"uri":"http:\/\/dbpedia.org\/resource\/Rafael_Nadal",
"group":1},
{
"name":"Grand_Slam_(tennis)",
"thumbnail":null,
"uri":"http:\/\/dbpedia.org\/resource\/Grand_Slam_(tennis)",
"group":1},
{
"name":"Toni_Nadal",
"thumbnail":"http:\/\/commons.wikimedia.org\/wiki\/Special:FilePath\/Toni_Nadal.jpg?width=300",
"uri":"http:\/\/dbpedia.org\/resource\/Toni_Nadal",
"group":0},
{
"name":"Australian_Open",
"thumbnail":"http:\/\/commons.wikimedia.org\/wiki\/Special:FilePath\/Australian_Open_2007_Night_Session.JPG?width=300",
"uri":"http:\/\/dbpedia.org\/resource\/Australian_Open",
"group":0},
{
"name":"Tennis_at_the_2008_Summer_Olympics_\u2013_Men's_singles",
"thumbnail":"",
"uri":"http:\/\/dbpedia.org\/resource\/Tennis_at_the_2008_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Men's_singles",
"group":0},
{
"name":"The_Championships,_Wimbledon",
"thumbnail":"http:\/\/commons.wikimedia.org\/wiki\/Special:FilePath\/Spencer_gore.jpg?width=300",
"uri":"http:\/\/dbpedia.org\/resource\/The_Championships,_Wimbledon",
"group":0},
{
"name":"Big_Four_(tennis)",
"thumbnail":"http:\/\/commons.wikimedia.org\/wiki\/Special:FilePath\/R_federer.jpg?width=300",
"uri":"http:\/\/dbpedia.org\/resource\/Big_Four_(tennis)",
"group":0}
],
"links":[
 {"source":1,"target":3,"prop":"coach","value":"coach"},
{"source":4,"target":2,"prop":"title","value":"title"},
{"source":4,"target":0,"prop":"menCurrent","value":"menCurrent"},
{"source":3,"target":1,"prop":"coachplayers","value":"coachplayers"},
{"source":5,"target":0,"prop":"bronze","value":"bronze"},
{"source":5,"target":1,"prop":"gold","value":"gold"},
{"source":5,"target":1,"prop":"goldMedalist","value":"goldMedalist"},
{"source":5,"target":0,"prop":"bronzeMedalist","value":"bronzeMedalist"},
{"source":6,"target":0,"prop":"menCurrent","value":"menCurrent"},
{"source":6,"target":2,"prop":"title","value":"title"},
{"source":7,"target":0,"prop":"caption","value":"caption"},
{"source":7,"target":1,"prop":"caption","value":"caption"},
{"source":3,"target":2,"prop":"coachtournamentrecord","value":"coachtournamentrecord"}
]
}
```

Some relation below.

```
 {"source":5,"target":1,"prop":"gold","value":"gold"},
 {"source":5,"target":1,"prop":"goldMedalist","value":"goldMedalist"},
```

My example don't show relation. It overlapping lines.
Please tell me why.

Comment: what is it youre trying to do exactly ?

Comment: I want to show all line (links) and linktexts on line (d.value)  between nodes . Now It's show but It overlapping lines. Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/71yrnaxe/5/

Your lines overlap because links connecting the same nodes have the same end and start points, what you need is some way to distinguish them. This is a bit hacky, but what it does is look through the links and give links with the same nodes different indexes in .multiLinkIndex -->

```
var mlink = d3.map();
graph.links.forEach (function(link) {
    var key = link.source+"-"+link.target;
    var i = mlink.has(key) ? mlink.get(key) + 1 : 0;
    mlink.set (key, i);
    link.multiLinkIndex = i;
});
```

then, when drawing the links we use this info to draw arcs of different radii between the nodes. The exact formula will need tinkering with I think but you can see in the fiddle the links are resolved individually. -->

```
var domLinks = [];
    link.attr("d", function(d,i) {
     domLinks[i] = this;
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) / (d.multiLinkIndex + 1) ;
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    });
```

The really hacky bit is using the link elements (stored in domLinks) to calculate positions for the link text elements halfway along the curved links, rather than halfway between the nodes, because these would still overwrite each other. Uses some code adjusted from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868

```
linkText
    /*
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return ((d.source.x + d.target.x)/2);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return ((d.source.y + d.target.y)/2);
    })
    */
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
            var domLink = domLinks[i];
         var l = domLink.getTotalLength();
         var p = domLink.getPointAtLength(l/2);
         return ("translate ("+p.x+","+p.y+")");
    })
    ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a good answer. Now I try to do according to your answers but It's still overlap in case graph have more than 2 links. 

Example 3 relation this. {"source":5,"target":1,"prop":"gold","value":"gold"},
    {"source":5,"target":1,"prop":"TestRalation3","value":"TestRalation3"},
 {"source":5,"target":1,"prop":"goldMedalist","value":"goldMedalist"},  http://bl.ocks.org/Lovekiizzk/e711683dd702533d15bd

Comment: You can play about with the dr formula a bit e.g. `dr = (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) * 2) * (1.0 / (d.multiLinkIndex + 1));` - but in the end you may have to set the link path up more explicitly - perhaps bezier curves that extend out d.multiLinkIndex * 10 pixels from the straight line to give a set separation

Comment: Thank you very much for a good answer. I try to change dr formula according to your answer and finally It' don't overlap. Thank you very very much.