# D3.js Don't Overlapping line but linktext not show

Tags: php, d3.js

### Don't Overlapping line but linktext not show

My question in stackoverflow.com 
[How to show many links separate by value in D3.js forced directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452187/how-to-show-many-links-separate-by-value-in-d3-js-forced-directed-graph/)

In the future I think line maybe overlapping althought I change dr formula because line is a semi-circular curve.

I search how to create curve line with another way. I see https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4600693 . I try to do and apply it to my data. See my new demo http://bl.ocks.org/Lovekiizzk/ab6fdec08beef4999839

```
//Appends link 
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(links)
.enter()
.append("g") // circle
.attr("class", "link")
.append("polyline") //if "line" It not show path
.attr("class", "link-line")
.style("stroke-width", 1)
//.attr("fill", "Black")
//.style("stroke-width", function (d) {  return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
.style("marker-mid",  "url(#end)");

//Appends link text
var linkText = svg.selectAll(".link")
.append("text")
.attr("class", "link-label")
//.attr("font-family", "tahoma, verdana, sans-serif")
.attr("fill", "Black")
.style("font", "normal 10px tahoma")
.attr("dy", ".15em")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

Now, Line (link) is not overlapping. It's very good. Text on node, Images instead circle and Link have arrow by direction is shown in my graph.   **but Linktext is not show.**

I want to show linktext by d.value

```
 "links":[
{"source":1,"target":3,"prop":"coach","value":"coach"},
{"source":4,"target":2,"prop":"title","value":"title"},
{"source":4,"target":0,"prop":"menCurrent","value":"menCurrent"},
{"source":3,"target":1,"prop":"coachplayers","value":"coachplayers"},
{"source":5,"target":0,"prop":"bronze","value":"bronze"},
{"source":5,"target":1,"prop":"gold","value":"gold"},
{"source":5,"target":1,"prop":"goldMedalist","value":"goldMedalist"},
{"source":5,"target":1,"prop":"TestRelation3","value":"TestRelation3"},
{"source":5,"target":0,"prop":"bronzeMedalist","value":"bronzeMedalist"},
{"source":6,"target":0,"prop":"menCurrent","value":"menCurrent"},
{"source":6,"target":2,"prop":"title","value":"title"},
{"source":7,"target":0,"prop":"caption","value":"caption"},
{"source":7,"target":1,"prop":"caption","value":"caption"},
{"source":3,"target":2,"prop":"coachtournamentrecord","value":"coachtournamentrecord"}
]
```

But It is Dnot show

Please tell me why. My english is very bad. Hope you don't mind.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your problems is that when you do a `svg.selectAll` to get all your `.link` elements, you no longer have any data connected to your selection.

Try this:

```
//Appends link 
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(links)
.enter()
.append("g") // circle
.attr("class", "link");

//Append circle
link.append("polyline") //if "line" It not show path
.attr("class", "link-line")
.style("stroke-width", 1)
//.attr("fill", "Black")
//.style("stroke-width", function (d) {  return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
.style("marker-mid",  "url(#end)");

//Appends link text
link.append("text")
.attr("class", "link-label")
//.attr("font-family", "tahoma, verdana, sans-serif")
.attr("fill", "Black")
.style("font", "normal 10px tahoma")
.attr("dy", ".15em")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try to do according to your answer. It still not show linktext and It not show line. I don't know I made mistake please tell me why. Thank you very much.